# Is it true in electrodynamics, that $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}=0$?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm just trying to verify if  $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}=0$ in electrodynamics.

Comment: Can you think of what conditions must occur for $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ for that statement to be true?

Comment: There is no such general rule, but there are some very important cases for which it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is true if $\vec B$ and $\vec E$ are mutually perpendicular to each other, like any ordinary vector.

Answer (score 7):

It is not evident from the vector notation that $\mathbf E\cdot\mathbf B$ is a relativistic invariant. Indeed
$$\mathbf E\cdot\mathbf B = \frac12\operatorname{Tr}(F{\star F}) = -\frac12F_{\mu\nu}(\star F)^{\mu\nu}.$$
However this is not invariant under parity, since this is just a pseudo-scalar, so it will take a sign under coordinate inversion. In principle there is no reason for this pseudo-scalar to be zero, but if you are dealing with Maxwell's equations in the vacuum, then $\mathbf E = \mathbf v \times\mathbf B$, and therefore you get 0 in the case of electromagnetic waves.